# Order of noun + modifying noun

Tags: nouns, word-order, appositives

Which one is correct or preferred?

1. The command */reload* is... < some description >
2. The */reload* command is... < some description >

Comment: Probly the second one. They're both grammatical, but since you have to choose one and stick to it, _The `/reload` command_ is probly the less irritating way to say it. It makes a fairly good header, too.

Comment: If you wish to identify the command you are about to describe then #2 is better.  If, instead, you are using */reload* as an example in a discussion of how commands are processed (or something of that nature) you would use #1.

Comment: I agree with Hot Licks. There is no *strict* preference, but there are situations where one would be better than other.

Comment: In the question itself there's no real difference but if you later try indexing every similar instance, 'the command /reload' will list all your commands together by category and 'the /reload command' will return everything alphabetically sub-sorted by commands and keywords and tokens and what have you.

Which, if either, works better goes beyod the original, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If you must use either "the X command" or "the command X" throughout the paper or article or manual you are writing, then I agree with John Lawler that "the X command" is probably the better choice because it sounds a bit more natural and therefore is less likely to intrude on the flow of the narrative by calling attention to itself.

However, I have read many articles that use both forms at different places in the same piece—and there's nothing wrong with doing that. Indeed, if your article walks readers through several dozen commands, one per paragraph, over the course of five or six print pages, readers will probably be grateful for some variety in the running-text presentation.

On the other hand, if each command name appears as a subhead or as an entry in a bulleted list, for example, the convenience of being able to scan the subheads or the list and not have to deal with complications arising from instances of transposed order (for example, X command, Y command, and command Z) trumps the "spice of life" argument in favor of variety.

Answer (score 1):

They have slightly different meanings, IMO.

The stop button is the button you use to stop the thing so the reload command is the command you use to reload the thing. This might or might not be */reload* in any given programming language.

Whilst you might get away with a */reload* command, the command */reload* is better because it makes it clear that you are talking about this particular command as opposed to any other command that also causes a reload. You would also have to do it this way if the command were more complicated. For example, in some imaginary language, you might say

> The command */reload(newdata,5)* is the reload command you use if you want to use new data and have a delay of 5 seconds.

The longer the command the more awkward it would be to put it before the word "command".

Answer (score -1):

(This was originally a comment, but my impression is that the other answers are not much less about readability and style than this is, so I'm throwing it out there as an "answer".)

Most of the time, I would say:

> Command **reload** is...

IMO, there are far too many extraneous "the" instances in most technical doc.

> The **AA** command checks whether the **BB** table has an index on the **CC** column, the **DD** column, and the **EE** column.

-->

> Command **AA** checks whether table **BB** has an index on columns **CC**, **DD**, and **EE**.

Answer (score -2):

The first sentence needs commas in order to be grammatically correct

> The command, reload, is assigned to the F5 key

without them, it sounds as if the `command` is being reloaded. *when written, at least*

> The command reload caused the computer to fail

Putting commas will add the pause needed to inflect the name of the command.

Comment: You are not addressing the OP's scenario.